# imagecreatefromstring returns "Resource id #7"

Tags: php, image-processing

I have image blob data and i want to watermark it. so i use the php function **imagecreatefromstring** to get an image. But the output for this image is `Resource id #7`.

When i do the headerinformation for Images (type,size) and echo the blob data, everything is fine.

What does `Resource id #7` mean?

Comment: See the example in the manual: http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource. Resources are created and used by special functions. See the
>   appendix for a listing of all these functions and the corresponding
>   resource types.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

You can use `get_resource_type` to find out what kind of resource is hiding in that variable.

Comment: get_resource_type = "gd". The main problem is to watermark the blob data image. How i get this as an image i can process im PHP?